# Button with 3 states using React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've got a need for a button with 3 states.

Each state, would need to handle click and send a value.

The use-case is:

- Non-favourite
- Favourite
- Uber-favourite

I tried using `this.state.count + 1` to indicated the levels, but had no success. I am unsure this is the best way either.

I am using the `const fill` as the CSS value (colour) I will pass into the `svg` element.

Here is my attempt, but it is limited as `checked` only has 2 states (on/off) and I need 3. It is also in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/oZaprP?editors=1111).

```
class Switch extends React.Component {
  constructor ( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      checked: !!props.checked
    };
  }
  handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
  }

  render () {
    const fill = this.state.checked ? "#E1E0DD" : "#999999";
    return (
        <button className="switch" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g>
          <path id="svg_2" d="m0,38l37,0l11,-38l11,38l37,0l-30,23l11,38l-30,-23l-30,23l11,-38l-30,-23l0,0z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill={fill} />
        </g>
      </svg>
            </button>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Switch checked={ true } />
    </div>
)

React.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "page" ) );
```

Comment: Why are you converting the props to a boolean? Why are you using booleans in the first place? Also, that's not how the ternary operator works! You're not even passing a `count` prop!

Comment: I updated my answer to my original attempt where I used `checked` instead. But this limits me

Comment: What's the point of passing a boolean when you have 3 states? Booleans have two possible values, true and false, which is not enough! Use an integer or something!

Comment: Yes that is why I posted on SO, so I could see a best-use example of how to do this simple task

Comment: just add modulus operator. `int % 3 === 1` and so on.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWzxeO

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

Firstly, don't derive a component's state from its props - this is an anti-pattern.

Secondly, because setState calls can be batched by React, you should use the `function(prevState, nextProps)` argument to setState rather than an object when you are basing new state on previous state.

Thirdly, as mentioned in the comment above, you are never going to be able to get three states by using a boolean.

I would implement this something like this:

```
class TripleSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       favourite: 0
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       favourite: (prevState.favourite + 1) % 3
    }));
  }

  render () {
    const { favourite } = this.state;
    const fill = favourite === 0 ? "#E1E0DD" :
                 favourite === 1 ? "#000444" : 
                 "#999999";
    return (
        <button className="switch" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g>
          <path id="svg_2" d="m0,38l37,0l11,-38l11,38l37,0l-30,23l11,38l-30,-23l-30,23l11,-38l-30,-23l0,0z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill={fill} />
        </g>
      </svg>
            </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `const favourite = { this.state };` give an unexpected token.

Comment: My mistake, brackets on the wrong side of the assignment.  I've edited.

Comment: Excellent. My last question would be, how would I send a different value depending on the state of the button? EG send value 1, 2, 3 with a handle submit?

Comment: If you are sending a request from within this component, then yes just send `this.state.favourite` which will have value 0,1 or 2.

Comment: If you have a parent component that handles the submission then you will need to [lift the state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) into the parent.

Comment: How would I `lift` is? I read your link but Im still unclear. Would using `xyz = this.state.favourite` then `handlesubmit(xyz)`, referring it to `this.props.xyz` be the way to use it?

Comment: Is this within a parent component?

Comment: No, within the same component

Answer (score 1):

I forked [your codepen](http://codepen.io/jonathandion/pen/oZaqXX)

A boolean value is 1 or 0. If you want 3 states you need to increment a value.

```
  handleClick(e) {
    var count = this.state.count;
    count = count !== 3 ? count + 1 : 0;
    this.setState({
      count: count
    });
  }
```

You should also separate your logic for the fill color:

```
function fillColor(count) {
    var fill = "";
    if(count === 1) fill = "#E1E0DD";
    if(count === 2) fill = "#999999";
    if(count === 3) fill = "#000";
    return fill;
}
```